# SwiftData how to release the relationship data after popping the view back

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have two data models. `Notebook` and `Memory`

There's one-to-many relationship between them, where each `Notebook` may have many `Memory` but each memory has one `Notebook` associated.

I have this notebook list view and I created a custom `Query`
I want the memories property to be faulted for `Notebooks`  in this view.
Even though, when the view is first loaded, the memories property is faulted.
When I select a notebook to navigate to the memory list view to see the list of memories, and when I pop the view back, I see that memory is the same as when I was on memory list view.

Seems like when I first clicked on a notebook, it loaded the memories of that notebook which is expected, however, **I want the memories to be faulted again when i return to the notebook list view.**

this is my current initializer for the notebook list view

```swift
init(sendEvent: @escaping (Event) -> Void) {
    var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Notebook>()
    self.sendEvent = sendEvent

    fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 30
    fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [
        SortDescriptor(\Notebook.creationDate, order: .reverse)
    ]

    self._notebooks = Query(fetchDescriptor)
}
```

I thought of experimenting with `FetchDescriptor.propertiesToFetch` to achieve my goal. I added a slight change.

```swift
init(sendEvent: @escaping (Event) -> Void) {
    var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Notebook>()
    self.sendEvent = sendEvent
    fetchDescriptor.propertiesToFetch = [
        \.id, \.color, \.name, \.creationDate
    ]
    fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = fetchLimit
    fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [
        SortDescriptor(\Notebook.creationDate, order: .reverse)
    ]

    self._notebooks = Query(fetchDescriptor)
}
```

However, this did not work. I need to reset the objects back to their faults. I wonder if this is possible in swiftdata

Comment: The problem seems to be with the color property, is it a custom type?

Comment: oh yeah it's a custom type it conforms to the codable protocol. I edited my post. propertiesToFetch seems to be working fine. Unfortunately it didnt help with the memory consumption after popping the child view. once the relationship fault is liften, it seems to be on the memory

Comment: I suppose i am looking something similar to this but for SwiftData I suppose i am looking something similar to this but for swift data https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506224-refresh

Comment: If you really need this kind of advanced functionality then maybe you should use Core Data instead?

Comment: maybe you're right it was a pet project to try out SwiftData and see how it goes. Thanks for taking the time to respond me.

Comment: Well propertiesToFetch, and a similar property for relationships, is completely undocumented so personally I will wait trying to use them until there’s more information available.